# A simple Python code in beginner level

Tags: python

I am new to Python and trying some easy stuff but i dont understand why my code is not working.

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140 * nights

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
        return 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    elif city == "Los Angeles":
        return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):
    cost = 40 * days
    if days >= 7:
        cost -= 50
    elif days >= 3 and days <= 6:
        cost -= 20
    return cost

def trip_cost(city, days, spending_money):
    return rental_car_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city) + hotel_cost(days) + spending_money
    print trip_cost("Los Angeles", 5, 600)
```

I tried this in different shells and some say syntax error on print trip_cost(...), and some say indentation error on <= 6:
im really confused.

Comment: Could you post the entire error?

Comment: `print(trip_cost("Los Angeles", 5, 600))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misaligned the printing the result of `trip_cost("Los Angeles", 5, 600)`.

```
def trip_cost(city, days, spending_money):
    return rental_car_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city) + hotel_cost(days) + spending_money

print trip_cost("Los Angeles", 5, 600)
```

The way you wrote the `trip_cost(...)` function now it will never print the value, as it is after the `return` from the function. To be able to print the value, you have to move the `print(trip_cost("Los Angeles", 5, 600))` outside of `trip_cost` body.

This way it will get printed.

Comment: @berkersoy: If my answer helped you, could you accept it? That way the problem will be marked as solved. (and we both get reputation)